# how to create a HtmlAnchor

Tags: htmlunit

I am surfing a page to get anchors containing a particular text. What I want to do is if no anchor satifies the criteria in that case the method should return a new HtmlAnchor pointing to the page I passed as a parameter.

```
public HtmlAnchor getAnchor(HtmlPage page, String criteria)
{
   if any anchor satisfies this criteria return that anchor 
   else create a new anchor pointing to the current page and return it //how to do this
}
```

FYI : I am using htmlunit 2.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't appear you can instantiate an `HtmlAnchor` directly, but you *can* create an instance of its parent, [HtmlElement](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlElement.html).   Set its "href" attribute to the url of that page, and you should have what you want.

What do you intend to do with it, though?

Comment: I found out a workaround, and yes you are right it can't be instantiated and it would rather be rude of me not to except a good answer.